# firebase push notification doesnt shows in all devices

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push notification to all devices from firebase but at first i tried only in my phone, it doesn't work, after that i tried in another phone and it doesn't work either. Finally with the 3rd one it work and it work at the second one magically. What i have to do to the push notifications work in all devices?

Manifest ->

```
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.startingandroid.firebasecloudmessaging">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="FCM"></activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application></manifest>
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService ->

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    //Getting registration token
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    //Displaying token in logcat
    Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
    //Not required for current project
} }
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService ->

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "StartingAndroid";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //It is optional
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    //Calling method to generate notification
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

//This method is only generating push notification
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}}
```

SplashActivity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }

    }, 4000);
}}
```

Comment: where are you sending the notifications from ? the Firebase console ?

Comment: yep, from firebase console to our phones connected

Comment: Was the app in foreground or background ?

Comment: at first i put it in backgroud. don't know why today works fine ^^. thank you very much for the anwers^^